# Not able to send text to Content-desc field using Appium with sendkeys() method

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate Google Hangouts app using appium(in java).

I am using Appium CLient v 1.3.7 I am using Samsung Galaxy S5 Android os version 5.0.

I want to send text using element.sendkeys() method to the field having content description as "Type a name,email,number or circle" field. Appium does find the field but after executing sendkeys() command, it does not show anything in the same field. ***Appium clicks at the left edge of the app.***

This field does not have resource-id. I tried element.click() before using sendkeys() but din't help. Any suggestion?

```js
dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capa);
WebElement el1 = dr.findElementByName("Type a name, email, number or circle");
el1.click();
el1.sendKeys("0000000");
```

Comment: Correct syntax is :  driver.findElement(By.name(name))

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I tried this driver.findElement(By.name(content-desc))  but it dint work too

Comment: What you want to do exactly? I have checked google Hangouts but not getting field which you have mentioned..

Comment: 1. Open Hangouts app on any android phone 2. Observe field with hint text  "Type a name,email,number or circle". . 3. You can find this field under contacts tab not in conversations. I want to automate this field and want to send any random mobiel number into this

Comment: posted updated comment

Comment: ok do you want to write something there?

Comment: wanna send any randome mobile number in there

Comment: check my answer and let me know if any issue in that.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have name which you are considering  , you can identify that element by following way :

```
WebElement el1  = driver.findElement(By.id("com.google.android.apps.hangouts:id/people_audience_view_chip_container")).click();

el1.sendKeys("0000000");
```

Comment: how did you get this id ? in uiAutomatorViewer i dint find any id to this element?

Comment: I am getting proper ID which I have shared. What issue do you getting?

Comment: are you able to send text to this field properly ? If yes can you please post the code ? Also which version of hangout are you using ?

Comment: I have not run it , I have just help you to find id. Can you please share your whole code to check..how you are opening hangout app and all so I can check...

Comment: First define desired capabilities and then                                                                                 dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capa);
WebElement el1 = dr.findElementByAccessibilityId("Type a name, email, number or circle");
 el1.sendKeys("123456");